# What is the history of graphic constructions since TeX?

Tags: graphics, tex-core, tex-history

With LaTeX, to natively build a figure, there is the `picture` mode. Today, there are also the `pstricks` and `TikZ` packages.
How was it originally done to draw figures in TeX? Was it possible?
I couldn't find anything about it in the TeXbook.

Comment: no idea, I don't use plain. But some of the packages on ctan mention plain tex.

Comment: Your answer comforts me, I'm not the only one who doesn't know. I wonder because TikZ is written in TeX (it seems) since it can be used in Plain TeX. And so there are TeX primitives (or macros) that can be used to make drawings. How it works, it's a real problem since it seems to me that Donald Knuth himself used another language *(Metafont)* to make drawings...

Comment: sorry I don't really get your problem. Naturally is tikz written in tex, what else? And it also works in plain.  And there are various packages for drawing which also works in plain, including metafont and metapost based. I only have no idea which a normal plain tex would use.

Comment: I'm sorry if I misspoke and misunderstood. From what little I learned from LaTeX, it's that initially to build drawings, there were Metafont, metapost and pstricks. None of these languages are written in TeX. Today, we use a lot of TikZ which is written in TeX. So TeX allows you to make drawings, but then why didn't we do that from the start? Why did we use Metapost and pstricks from the beginning?

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator (free version)

Comment: tikz is not completly written in tex. it uses postscript when used with dvips, see e.g. pgfsys-common-postscript.def. And the other backends have special commands too.

Comment: Does this mean that finally, everything written with TeX is "translated" (compiled ?) into postscript language, which itself is compiled into PDF?

Comment: If you create directly a pdf then it is translated into pdf, if you write a svg it is svg and so on. How else should it work?

Comment: If I understand well, it is thus the drivers svg, pdf which make the drawings, TeX does not know how to draw, there are no primitives or macros in Plain Tex which makes it possible to make drawings. Tex is thus from this point of view a software overlay of the svg, pdf drivers, right?

Comment: Perhaps my view is too simplistic, but ...  The first instance of TeX had one purpose: to place elements from fonts at specific locations on a surface.  Nothing that could be construed as graphics.  And there was a specific module for each intended output device.  Only later was the `dvi` (device-indepndent) concept applied.  So I'd say that it's *independent* software; its relation to anything else is essentially irrelevant.  Hence no need to mention graphics or drawing in the TeXbook.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I understand perfectly what you are saying because you had the chance to live the TeX adventure alongside Donald Knuth. I arrived very recently in the world of TeX and LaTeX and what seems obvious to those who have lived this construction since the beginning is for me a source of astonishment and questioning. I notice that LaTeX introduces a `picture` environment that allows you to make drawings. As LaTeX is a set of macros written in TeX, I wonder how people used to make drawings before LaTeX. Did we use Metapost, metafont, pstricks? Did we only make drawings?

Comment: There have been various programs devised for making drawings using a computer, but I'm the wrong person to ask.  The only real drawings I've ever made were with india ink and a ruling pen; I spent two summers while I was an undergraduate as an engineering draftsman drawing plots of wind tunnel profiles.  Since then, the closest I've gotten to that is flowcharts.  And not on a computer.  Sorry I can't help.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I think what you experienced is representative of what was common practice at the time: no one was using the computer to make drawings.  LaTeX was only used to write mathematical equations and formulas, not to draw geometric figures. The idea of making geometric figures must have been born with the arrival of LaTeX. The figures had to be made with India ink on an architect's table like you did yourself.

Comment: Not entirely true.  The person I was drawing the plots for had a little analog device that would draw rough images based on the data, which he used to make sure I was getting the correct (quite refined) images.  (I was hired on the basis of a recommendation by my Girl Scout leader, who was a graduate student in the department.)  He only fessed up after I had delivered good work, and on that basis, I was hired again for the second summer.  There *were* computer programs for engineering and architectural work, but they were expensive, and the plotting tables took a lot of space.

Comment: @barbarabeeton True, but this person wasn't using TeX to do his drawings.

Comment: @AndréC I'm the least qualified person on TeX history, but before output formats with graphic capabilities (PostScript is one of the earliest, I believe), one technique used to get pictures in a TeX document was to get make a font with line and curve segments, then carefully position these segments to get a picture.  This is what the built-in version of the `picture` environment does (try `{\tenln abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\par}` in a LaTeX document).  Knuth also shows an example of that in appendix D of the TeXBook (search for `\dragon`).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I just tried `tenlm{}` and I see the little segments and the arrows. Even if that doesn't answer the question, your comment is a **considerable step forward in understanding this story**. Can you explain that in more detail in response?

Comment: off topic: How the score of post is (-1) in meta but it is +18 here!!

Comment: @C.F.G I have no idea, it's a great mystery.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Disclaimer: some pieces and facts in this answer may be inaccurate (most of the historical facts found around the web), so take it with a grain of salt (corrections welcome).

---

## The DVI format

TeX's DVI format is the simplest possible format to produce typeset output: it knows only about boxes, glue and rules.  A character is a box that references a glyph in a font file, possibly separated by the next box by some glue.  The glyphs themselves are not known by DVI; it only links them to a font file, and the DVI viewer/printer is responsible for placing the glyphs in the proper boxes (there's a [“DVI standard”](http://mirrors.ctan.org/dviware/driv-standard/level-0/dvistd0.pdf) you might find interesting).  There's no space for graphics here, so Knuth added (for this and other purpose) another item to TeX's output: a `\special`;  this primitive adds some command to the output file directly, and this command ought to be interpreted by the output device (for instance, with `\special{pdf:q 1 j 0 1 0 rg 0 0 1 RG 0 0 10 10 re B Q}\bye` (from [`samplepdf.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/doc/pdftex/samplepdftex/samplepdf.tex) and running with pdfTeX you get a [image] in the output).

These `\specials` require an output device that understands them.  The PDF format was only [created in 1993](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF), which is recent in terms of TeX history.  Before that, we had PostScript [created in 1984](https://www.prepressure.com/postscript/basics/history), a bit later than TeX.  However the `dvips` program, used to translate TeX's DVI output into PostScript files was only created around 1986 (see [this interview](https://tug.org/interviews/rokicki.html) with `dvips` creator Tomas Rokicki).

## Drawing with fonts

Before the creation of `dvips` all they had were boxes with font glyphs in them, so that's what was used.  Knuth says in Appendix D of The TeXbook:

> If you enjoy fooling around making pictures, instead of typesetting
> ordinary text, TeX will be a source of endless frustration/amusement
> for you, because almost anything is possible if you have suitable fonts.

(the [tikz-pgf](/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf) tag is here to prove how true that statement is :-)

One example of that is the `manfnt` font, used throughout the TeX and METAFONT books for miscellaneous glyphs.  For example, if you do:

```
\font\qc=manfnt
\qc abcd \char127
\bye
```

you'll get four quarter circles, stored in positions `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` of that font, an the famous Dangerous Bend sign:

> [image]

Knuth also shows some handy macros for those quarter circles so you can make pictures out of them.  One of the examples given is the Dragon Curve, which uses carefully placed boxes containing `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`, of the `manfnt`:

```
\font\qc=manfnt
\catcode`\ =9 \endlinechar=-1 % ignore all spaces (temporarily)
\newcount\dir \newdimen\y \newdimen\w
\newif\ifvisible \let\B=\visibletrue \let\W=\visiblefalse
\newbox\NE \newbox\NW \newbox\SE \newbox\SW \newbox\NS \newbox\EW
\setbox\SW=\hbox{\qc a} \setbox\NW=\hbox{\qc b}
\setbox\NE=\hbox{\qc c} \setbox\SE=\hbox{\qc d}
\w=\wd\SW \dimen0=\fontdimen8\qc
\setbox\EW=\hbox{\kern-\dp\SW \vrule height\dimen0 width\wd\SW} \wd\EW=\w
\setbox\NS=\hbox{\vrule height\ht\SW depth\dp\SW width\dimen0}  \wd\NS=\w
\def\L{\ifcase\dir \dy+\NW \or\dx-\SW \or\dy-\SE \or\dx+\NE\dd-4\fi \dd+1}
\def\S{\ifcase\dir \dx+\EW \or \dy+\NS \or \dx-\EW \or \dy-\NS \fi}
\def\R{\ifcase\dir \dy-\SW\dd+4 \or\dx+\SE \or\dy+\NE \or\dx-\NW\fi \dd-1}
\def\T{\ifcase\dir\kern-\w\dd+2\or\ey-\dd+2\or\kern\w\dd-2\or\ey+\dd-2\fi}
\edef\dd#1#2{\global\advance\dir#1#2\space}
\def\dx#1#2{\ifvisible\raise\y\copy#2 \if#1-\kern-2\w\fi\else\kern#1\w\fi}
\def\dy#1#2{\ifvisible\raise\y\copy#2 \kern-\w \fi \global\advance\y#1\w}
\def\ey#1{\global\advance\y#1\w}
\def\path#1{\hbox{\B \dir=0 \y=0pt #1}}
\catcode`\ =10 \endlinechar=`\^^M % resume normal spacing conventions
\newcount\n % the current order in the \dragon and \nogard macros
\def\dragon{\ifnum\n>0{\advance\n-1 \dragon\L\nogard}\fi}
\def\nogard{\ifnum\n>0{\advance\n-1 \dragon\R\nogard}\fi}
% end of definitions
\centerline{\path{\dir=3 \n=9 \dragon}}
\bye
```

which produces:

> [image]

If you replace `manfnt` by, say, `cmtt10` you can see that clearly:

> [image]

This same approach is used by LaTeX (2.09 at the time; the earliest date mentioned in the sources is 1991/08/14, but there's a TUG Boat article by Rainer Schöpf [from 1989](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb10-1/tb23schopf.pdf), so it probably existed for much longer than that), implemented in the `picture` environment.  The environment has a collection of commands like `\put`, `\line`, `\circle`, etc., which use specially crafted fonts that contain line and circle segments, and places these segments one next to the other to form a picture.

To see these fonts in action you can try:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
{\tenln abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\par}
\end{document}
```

to see some of the glyphs available (or use the `fonttable` package):

> [image]

The problem with this approach is that you can only have so many different lines in a font file, and as soon as you start to try it out you'll find the limitations.  For instance you only have a finite amount of line angles, and anything in between doesn't work (try `\put(0,0){\vector(259,966){1}}`), and you also have circles at fixed steps and up to a maximum radius (try `\put(0,0){\circle{40}} \put(0,0){\circle{50}}` with the default value of `\unitlength`).  Take a look at the [`pict2e` package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pict2e/pict2e.pdf): it contains some nice comparisons of legacy font-based pictures and “modern” (after PostScript, so 1985 :-) techniques.

Both Knuth's `manfnt` and LaTeX's `line10` (the font in `\tenln`) are made using METAFONT, so in a weird way that was one of the first pieces of software used to add graphics natively (or as close to that as possible) in TeX.

#### PiCTeX

A rather interesting piece of software developed in the late 80s by Michael Wichura is PiCTeX ([TUGboat article](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb09-2/tb21wichura-pictex.pdf)).  PiCTeX is a macro package that defines its own drawing mechanisms:  to draw curves it uses several dots placed one next to the other, overlapping so that at a reading distance it looks like a continuous line.

The package defines its own syntax for drawing things, for example to draw a quarter circle with center at (0,0), from (5,0) to (0,5) you'd use:

```
\beginpicture
\circulararc 90 degrees from 5 0 center at 0 0
\endpicture
```

You can replace the `manfnt` characters with quarter circles draw with PiCTeX in the Dragon Curve above to get the same curve (code for this at the end of the answer, to avoid clutter).  If you zoom in you can see the dots:

> [image]

You can have fun with `\setplotsymbol(<symbol>)` to replace the dot by `<symbol>` (`\setplotsymbol(?)` gives a nice effect) and `\plotsymbolspacing=<distance>` to set the distance between the dots. Mind you that PiCTeX uses a *lot* of dots, an TeX has to hold all of them in the same page, so you might exhaust its memory quickly (in fact that happened frequently back in the day, for nontrivial pictures).  You can find a summary of PiCTeX commands [here](http://tug.ctan.org/info/pictex/summary/pictexsum.pdf), and some useful examples [here](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/maad/maad.tex), and a list of sources [here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/pictex/Doc-PiCTeX.txt).  Unfortunately, although PiCTeX is free, its manual is not (you can order a copy [here](https://pctex.com/books.html), but I doubt it's useful for more than historical curiosity nowadays).

## PostScript

A few years later PostScript, a full-fledged programming language, was developed by Adobe (or Adobe was born from PostScript).  Its main intent is to be a page description language, so most of its features align with TeX's DVI, but it has many more features, including drawing and (limited) colour support from the start.  Then, in 1986 Tomas Rokicki wrote the `dvips` program to convert DVI files into PostScript, so TeX could benefit from that.  This allowed for the use of `\special`s that would write PostScript code into the page, so with something like:

```
\special{ps:
50 50 scale
newpath 1 1 moveto
 0  1 rlineto  1  0 rlineto
 0 -1 rlineto -1  0 rlineto
closepath
gsave 0 1 0 setrgbcolor fill grestore
0 0 1 setrgbcolor
0.05 setlinewidth
stroke}
\bye
```

and running `tex <file>.tex` then `dvips <file>.dvi` you'd get a `<file>.ps` with a [image], similar to the PDF command from before.

But bear in mind that TeX still knows absolutely nothing about colour or drawings:  it just forwards the `\special` to the DVI file, then `dvips` picks that up and passes it to the PostScript device to do its thing.

Some time later (around 1993<sup>[[1](https://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks-base),[2](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb15-3/tb44tvz.pdf)]</sup>) Timothy Van Zandt brought PSTricks (PS stands for PostScript) into the world: a PostScript graphics macro interface for TeX and LaTeX.  This macro layer provides commands with key-value interface which eventually translate into PostScript `\special`s.  The picture from the example above could be rewritten:

```latex
\input pstricks
\psframe[fillstyle=solid,linecolor=blue,
  fillcolor=green](1,1)
\bye
```

## PDF

Around that time, Adobe was developing the PDF format, which was supposed to be a system-independent version of PostScript.  It didn't include a programming language, but it also had drawing and colour capabilities.  A few years later (1996<sup>[[1](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdftex?lang=en)]</sup> Hàn Thế Thành wrote pdfTeX: a TeX engine capable of producing PDF files directly, rather having to use `dvips` then `ps2pdf`.  This would allow you to do more or less the same as you did with PostScript, but using PDF commands:

```
\special{pdf:
q
 1 j
 0 1 0 rg
 0 0 1 RG
 0 0 10 10 re
B
Q}
\bye
```

## Into the 21st century and user interfaces

The increasing popularity of computers and computational power several other software appeared to add to the mix.  The main ones are XeTeX with an updated output format eXtended DVI (XDV), LuaTeX which uses a similar backend as pdfTeX, but with a few quirks, output to web formats like HTML (using `tex4ht`) and SVG (using `dvisvgm`).  With all these options, basic support packages for graphics and colour adopted a layer of abstraction called a “driver- (or backend-) specific file”.  This makes things much easier, because at the macro layer you can say `\driver@line{0,0}{10,10}`, then the `\driver@line` macro would have the proper definition of (roughly) `\special{pdf:0 0 m 10 10 l b}` if the output format is PDF or `\special{ps:0 0 moveto 10 10 lineto stroke}` for PostScript or `<path d="M 0 0 l 10 10" />` for SVG (just an example, the output for these commands will vary in size and position).

Packages like `pict2e` extend LaTeX's `picture` environment to produce more or less the same it would with the legacy font-based output, but instead it uses these driver-specific routines, so you can use the package in any engine you like and the driver files will take care of that for you.

From this point on, further abstractions are created on the macro layer to make it easy (terms and conditions may apply) to draw in LaTeX.  The biggest example of that is Ti*k*Z, which adds an enormous amount of user-friendliness to make `\draw (0,0) -- (10,10);` translate eventually to `\driver@line{0,0}{10,10}` then `\special{pdf:0 0 m 10 10 l b}`.  Of course it's not that simple, but the principle remains.

---

Again, this is not complete nor completely accurate (most of this happened when I was a toddler), but I hope it gives you a sense of how things were back in the day.

---

#### Code for PiCTeX Dragon Curve

```latex
\input pictex
% \setplotsymbol(?)
% \plotsymbolspacing=1pt
% \plotsymbolspacing=0.01pt % exceeds TeX's memory
\def\pictx#1#2#3#4{%
  \beginpicture
  \setplotarea x from -5 to 5, y from -5 to 5
  \circulararc 90 degrees from #1 #2 center at #3 #4
  \endpicture}
\font\qc=manfnt

\catcode`\ =9 \endlinechar=-1 % ignore all spaces (temporarily)
\newcount\dir \newdimen\y \newdimen\w
\newif\ifvisible \let\B=\visibletrue \let\W=\visiblefalse
\newbox\NE \newbox\NW \newbox\SE \newbox\SW \newbox\NS \newbox\EW
\setbox\SW=\hbox{\pictx{-5}{-5}{-10}{-5}}
\setbox\NW=\hbox{\pictx{-10}{0}{-10}{5}}
\setbox\NE=\hbox{\pictx{-5}{5}{0}{5}}
\setbox\SE=\hbox{\pictx{0}{0}{0}{-5}}
\w=\wd\SW \dimen0=\fontdimen8\qc
\setbox\EW=\hbox{\kern-\dp\SW \vrule height\dimen0 width\wd\SW} \wd\EW=\w
\setbox\NS=\hbox{\vrule height\ht\SW depth\dp\SW width\dimen0}  \wd\NS=\w
\def\L{\ifcase\dir \dy+\NW \or\dx-\SW \or\dy-\SE \or\dx+\NE\dd-4\fi \dd+1}
\def\S{\ifcase\dir \dx+\EW \or \dy+\NS \or \dx-\EW \or \dy-\NS \fi}
\def\R{\ifcase\dir \dy-\SW\dd+4 \or\dx+\SE \or\dy+\NE \or\dx-\NW\fi \dd-1}
\def\T{\ifcase\dir\kern-\w\dd+2\or\ey-\dd+2\or\kern\w\dd-2\or\ey+\dd-2\fi}
\edef\dd#1#2{\global\advance\dir#1#2\space}
\def\dx#1#2{\ifvisible\raise\y\copy#2 \if#1-\kern-2\w\fi\else\kern#1\w\fi}
\def\dy#1#2{\ifvisible\raise\y\copy#2 \kern-\w \fi \global\advance\y#1\w}
\def\ey#1{\global\advance\y#1\w}
\def\path#1{\hbox{\B \dir=0 \y=0pt #1}}
\catcode`\ =10 \endlinechar=`\^^M % resume normal spacing conventions
\newcount\n % the current order in the \dragon and \nogard macros
\def\dragon{\ifnum\n>0{\advance\n-1 \dragon\L\nogard}\fi}
\def\nogard{\ifnum\n>0{\advance\n-1 \dragon\R\nogard}\fi}
% end of definitions
\centerline{\path{\dir=3 \n=9 \dragon}}
\bye
```

Comment: Thank you for this rich answer and its links to historical sources that I am reading carefully (and I'm not finished yet). Many thanks for telling us this story in such an exciting way.

Comment: Great answer, but it skims over PiCTeX, which was able to draw quadratic Bézier curves using dots; you could go out for a drink, while waiting for a diagram to compile.

Comment: @egreg I saw some mentions of PiCTeX but didn't bother looking (I thought it was yet another extension to `picture`).  Shame on me, it's a really interesting package. I added something to my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @egreg and Phelype. About PiCTeX, the TUGBoat article is a presentation of its possibilities. I didn't see any mention to any driver or postcript . Does it use tiny boxes of one TeX point `pt` dimension to make the drawings?

Comment: there were several dvi to ps convertors before dvips, dvitops, dvi2ps, dvipsone,

Comment: Didn't the DVI format originate from David Fuchs? (https://www.overleaf.com/blog/618-an-interview-with-david-fuchs-tex-pioneer-and-designer-of-the-dvi-file-format).

Comment: picture mode was in latex 0.9 (for tex 0.95) not sure of the date that was written, the archived files have a file date of 1983

Comment: “Of course it's not that simple” … that must be the understatement of the year!

Comment: @AndréC PiCTeX uses the box (with a `.`) and glue (`\kern` and `\raise`/`\lower`) model, so it doesn't need any driver-specific feature; it only needs a font with a `.` in it (and lots of memory :-).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Ok, what about this `However PICTeX can be used as an interface between TEX and a sophisticated graphics program. For example, Figure 2 was set using Fig and a Fig-to-PICTEX converter developed by Micah Beck` ?   Is it a driver? What does it mean by interface?

Comment: @AndréC I'm not sure what Michael means with that statement.  Maybe he means that you can use a drawing program to generate the PiCTeX code, then PiCTeX does the drawing (in an analogy, think of PGF as similar to PiCTeX: it draws on paper; and think of Ti*k*Z as such interface program: you write something like `\draw(0,0)--(1,1);` and it translates to the lower level PGF/PiCTeX command).  In this case PiCTeX would behave as the “backend graphics device” (although it's not).  I think the Fig-to-PiCTeX program Michael refers to is this one: https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb11-3/tb29beck.pdf

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I think your answer would be even more relevant if you put this story into perspective with the technological capabilities of the time. It's a context that has been forgotten today when everyone can carry a smartphone that is much more powerful than the first computers of the time.  The first Mac Intosh dates back to 1984 with a memory of 128K, computers were mainly reserved for large companies and universities, etc.. Universities usually had a single supercomputer shared with students by appointment. 

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator (free version)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Before the creation of postscript, how was it possible to print a page? Was there a driver that converted dvi files for specific printers or was there a language equivalent to postscript?

Comment: have you never watched a dot matrix printer do 9 passes per line and 15 minutes or so per page and draw  `epic` curves by micro positioned dots..... @AndréC

Comment: @AndréC with reference tp fig and pictex you can still use xfig now, and see its tex back ends

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, but these printers need a driver, unless they understand DVI?

Comment: @AndréC all tex systems of the day had dvi drivers for such printer look at the printers listed in `modes.mf`  things like `mode_def newdd =                    %\[ DataDisc (70x93dpi)
`  so printing on very low resolution printers

Comment: @AndréC eg http://4tex.ntg.nl/4tex4/4texdoc/4tse40.htm

Comment: And then there was MetaPost, which is now embedded in LuaTeX as a library. And of course we have tikz/pgf.